# What is my JSON file consist of?

Tags: json

I have read tutorials on the syntax of JSON files but I am still not quite sure I got it. Here is my JSON file:

```
{
  "dataset": [
    {
      "seriesname": "Item1 Price",
      "data": [
        {
          "value": 4.72
        },
        {
          "value": 2.81
        },
        {
          "value": 6.18
        },
        {
          "value": 5.17
        },
        {
          "value": 2.94
        },
        {
          "value": 3.77
        },
        {
          "value": 1.7
        },
        {
          "value": 6.72
        },
        {
          "value": 4.61
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "seriesname": "Item2 Price",
      "data": [
        {
          "value": 2.49
        },
        {
          "value": 0.72
        },
        {
          "value": 4.06
        },
        {
          "value": 1.74
        },
        {
          "value": 7.23
        },
        {
          "value": 5.83
        },
        {
          "value": 2.59
        },
        {
          "value": 7.54
        },
        {
          "value": 7.02
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    {
      "label": "Jan"
    },
    {
      "label": "Feb"
    },
    {
      "label": "Mar"
    },
    {
      "label": "Apr"
    },
    {
      "label": "May"
    },
    {
      "label": "Jun"
    },
    {
      "label": "Jul"
    },
    {
      "label": "Aug"
    },
    {
      "label": "Sept"
    }
  ]
}
```

From what I understand, there are 2 JSONObjects here, one is "dataset" and another is "categories". The "dataset" object has 2 JSONObjects inside it (Item1 Price and Item2Price) and they both are arrays which have several values. "categories" is an array with several entries. Am I correct or am I misreading the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct.  You can use any of the JSON visualizers out there (just google that term) to 'see' the data structure of the JSON array...

for example the one I use often is [located here](http://jsoneditoronline.org/).

if you paste your JSON data in the left column, then click the arrow in the middle pointing to the right, it will let you navigate and explore the data easily (see screenshot below).

[image]

When I started working with JSON it really helped me visualize the syntax and structure of some complex data I was working with.

Good luck!